# didBeginContact not calling GameOver scene. Does something need to be added?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have different colored bars on the right side of my screen with other bars of the same colors generated randomly coming from the left side that are to be matched with the static ones on the right. When matching colors collide, they are incrementing my score label and removing from the scene perfectly fine, but when the wrong ones match up, nothing happens. Ive even set up a `print("")` statement and its not being called. Here is my code for `didBeginContact`:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

  if let firstBody = ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA.node : contact.bodyB.node) as! SKSpriteNode? {

     if let secondBody = ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyB.node : contact.bodyA.node) as! SKSpriteNode? {

        if firstBody.color == secondBody.color {
           label.text = "\(points)"
           points++

           firstBody.removeFromParent()


        }
        if firstBody.color != secondBody.color { 
           gameEnd()
           print("didn't match")

        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Didn't I answer this question last night?  Anyway this new code will not work, and I am not even sure how it is compiling,  secondBody scope should be local to the if statement, so by the time you do the color != part secondBody is nil

Comment: I figured out the collisions, but the gameOver isn't wanting to work which is why i asked ( the rest is working how it should). Where should the != statement go so it won't be nil?

Comment: When I change up the order (if color == color) {  gameEnd() it works fine. Is the last statement even correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be an unorganized mess,  give this a try:

```
       func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

            if let firstBody = ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA.node : contact.bodyB.node) as! SKSpriteNode?,  secondBody = ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyB.node : contact.bodyA.node) as! SKSpriteNode? {

              if firstBody.color == secondBody.color {
                 label.text = "\(points)"
                 points++
                 firstBody.removeFromParent()
              }
              else{ 
                  print("didn't match")
                  gameEnd()
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: explain better than didnt work,  I am going off of a hypothetical here

Comment: Its doing the exact same thing as the code I posted in my question (not calling gameEnd)

Comment: then you are not hitting a spot where colorA != colorB

Comment: print the colors, make sure that it is your block color, and not white or black (I forget what default is)

Comment: What if one of the colors is `UIColor.blackColor()`? Would that be messing me up?

Comment: Is one of your blocks black?

Comment: Yes, and I have a white one(they're all basic UI Colors)

Comment: ok, well then give your blocks names,  and print the name, and make sure that the block name has the color you want

Comment: Yea, its all printing fine.

Comment: if it was fine you wouldnt be having a problem

Comment: The issue is not this code, the issue is that firstBody.color is always equal to secondBody.color, so we have an issue with firstBody and secondBody, and we need to find out why these bodies are not what you want